# Ajax/Javascript How to log this error?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am trying to build a Chrome extension where you can land on any webpage and click on the extension, which will grab the page's title and URL. The extension then sends this data to a form hosted on a specific website and submits the form.

My Chrome extension console is not currently logging any errors, yet the data appears to not be sending. I can't figure out how to get sent whatever error is occurring -- right now the error that I get is just my website's HTML; before when I was messing around with the error field I was getting [object object].

Here is my Javascript file:

```
function getCurrentTabUrl(callback) {
    var queryInfo = {
      active: true,
      currentWindow: true
    };

    chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
      var tab = tabs[0];
      var url = tab.url;
      console.assert(typeof url == 'string', 'tab.url should be a string');
      callback(url);
    });
}

function getCurrentTabTitle(callback) {
    var queryInfo = {
      active: true,
      currentWindow: true
    };
    chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function(tabs) {
      var tab = tabs[0];
      var title = tab.title;
      callback(title);
    });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    getCurrentTabTitle(function(title) {
      console.log('TITLLEEEEEEEEE' + title)

        getCurrentTabUrl(function(url) {
          console.log('URLLLLLLL' + url)

            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: website,
              data: "clips_url="+ url +"clips_article_title="+ title,
              success: "success",
              dataType: String,
              error: function(errorMessage) {
                  console.log('ERROR: ' + errorMessage.responseText);            
              }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please format your code for better reading. it's hard to see where open/close brackets line-up

Comment: Add a success function as well as an error function.  At least that will rule out whether or not the data is being posted.